# What Akka Java classes to implement Future callbacks with?

Tags: java, callback, akka

Akka **Java** here. My classes:

```
class SomeActor extends UntypedActor {
    // ...
}

class SomeMessage {
    // ...
}

// Inside onReceive method for another actor:
Future<Fizz> fizzFut = Patterns.ask(someActor, someMsg, 500)
fizzFut.onComplete(new FizzHandler())

class FizzHandler extends akka.dispatch.OnComplete<Fizz> {
    @Override
    void onComplete(Throwable error, Fizz result) {
        if(error != null) {
            // Handle error.
        } else {
            // Handle success.
        }

        // TODO: Now how do I send a message back "inside" the
        // actor system?
    }
}
```

At runtime I get the following exception:

```
[ERROR] [08/23/2015 05:55:09.490] [myapp-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4]
[akka://myapp/user/AnotherActor] No signature of method: 
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.onComplete() is applicable for argument
types: (com.me.myapp.FizzHandler) values: [<function1>]
Possible solutions: onComplete(scala.Function1, scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext),
isCompleted(), complete(scala.util.Try), tryComplete(scala.util.Try)
```

So I tried implementing a `scala.Function` subclass but apparently that class is `final` and cannot be extended.

So two concerns here:

- I can't decipher what Java API classes I should be using for my `onComplete` handler. Any ideas?; and
- Once I get this working, and the `FizzHandler#onComplete(...)` method is running, how do I send a message back "inside" my actor system? The `Inbox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example using onComplete you're missing the dispatcher. onComplete takes 2 parameters - the `handler` function and the `dispatcher` which should be used to run the call-back on once it's ready. So the fixed sample is:

```
    import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
    import akka.dispatch.Futures;
    import akka.dispatch.OnComplete;
    import scala.concurrent.Future;
    import scala.runtime.BoxedUnit;

    final ActorSystem sys = ActorSystem.create();

    final Future<String> successful = Futures.successful("");
    successful.onComplete(new OnComplete<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Throwable failure, String success) throws Throwable {

        }
    }, sys.dispatcher());
```

Note that once Scala 2.12 hits it's stable release and Akka compiles using it (soon) it will emit `FunctionN` classes in a compatible way with Java lambda expressions, then you'll be able to write `onComplete(d -> {}, dispatcher)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Akka *2.3.8* and scala *2.10*:

I use the **separate** `onFailure` and `onSuccess` methods which take an `akka.dispatch.OnFailure` and `akka.dispatch.OnSuccess<T>` respectively. For example:

```
future.onFailure(new OnFailure() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable failure) throws Throwable {
        // handle failure
    }
}, context().dispatcher());
```

and

```
future.onSuccess(new OnSuccess<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object result) throws Throwable {
        // handle successful value return
    }
}, context().dispatcher());
```

(if you're calling this outside an actor you'll have to change where you get the dispatcher)

Comment: Thanks @Chris Mowforth (+1) - quick question about the `onFailure` handler: when `someActor` (that is, the actor being "asked") throws an exception, who gets notified? The `onFailure` handler, the parent of `someActor`, or both?

Comment: @smeeb the actor's parent via the supervision strategy, and whatever thread ends up executing the `onFailure` callback method [somebody correct me if I'm wrong!].

Comment: When the target ("asked") actor throws Actor supervision ( http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/supervision.html#supervision ) will be notified. It will *NOT* automatically do anything with the "ask Future", thus the Future will eventually throw with a time-out. This is to allow various patterns around recovering. There is a big warning about these semantics in the docs about ask, read that to learn more: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/untyped-actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future